# If $G(x) = \int_{a}^{x}g$ is differentiable at $c$, is $G'(c) = g(c)$?

Tags: calculus

Let $g$ be integrable on $[a,b]$ with $a < c < b$ and suppose that $G$ is differentiable at $c$, where $$G(x) = \int_{a}^{x}g. $$Can we conclude that $G'(c) = g(c)$?

Note: this was posed as a question on my exam. The answer was no, we cannot, but in the actual question G was defined as $G(x)= \int_{0}^{x}g$. Obviously if $G$ is defined in this way the question is false, as $G$ is assumed integrable only on $[a,b]$, where it is not necessarily true that $0 \in [a,b]$. But I'm wondering if this was just a typo, and if the statement is still false if $G$ is defined as the integral from $a$ to $b$.

Comment: For instance, take $g = \mathbf{1}_C$ as the indicator function of the Cantor set $C$. Then $g$ is integrable (both in Riemann sense and in Lebesgue sense) and $G(x) = \int_a^x g$ is identically zero, yet $G'(x) = 0 \neq 1 = g(x)$ for every $x \in C$.

Comment: Consider $g=x$ for $x\neq 1, g(1)=25$. Now, what is $G'(1)$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The point is that $g$ can be redefined on a set of measure zero without
changing anything. So for any given $c$ you cannot conclude that $G'(c) = g(c)$.

Answer (score 0):

Take $g=\mathbb{1}_{\mathbb{Q}\cap [a,b]}$. You then have $$G(x) = \int_a^x g = 0$$
for all $x\in[a,b]$, so that $G$ is differentiable everywhere (it is even $C^\infty$). Yet $G^\prime(x) \neq g(x)$ for every $x\in \mathbb{Q}\cap [a,b]$.

(You *do* have $G^\prime(x) = g(x)$ almost everywhere, however: this is not a coincidence, since [it is a consequence of (a generalization of) the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus#Generalizations).)